# Change position of the info window

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, position, infowindow

I usually see the info window is opened to the top of the marker. is there any way that i can open it to bottom or side? I mean left side or right side?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to specify the `anchorPoint` property on the Marker: *"The offset from the marker's position to the tip of an InfoWindow that has been opened with the marker as anchor.*"

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions

Comment: Hi Duncan. When I set anchorPoint attribute, the infoWindow opens in a new point. However, it's not pointing to the marker. Could you tell me how to make that happen? I believe that would add more value to your answer.

Comment: You should probably ask this as a new question, so I can see some of your code

Comment: @jdjuan sorry, I can't recall at this time.

Answer (score 2):

[image: screenshot]
The way info window is opened, as you probably referring to this... google map window
play with css position:absolute; try change those values of top and left co-ordinate and see how, it moves around with the shadow.